Symmetric vector fields on the sphere
Let $C$ be a closed curve on $S^2$ (possibly self-intersecting) that is symmetric with respect to the origin. Assume a unit tangent vector field $F$ is defined on $C$ with $F(x)=F(-x)$ for all $x\in C$. Is the winding number of $F$ necessarily zero?
I think the answer is yes, and this is the argument I have come up with. Could someone check my proof below?
Proof.
The winding number of a vector field $F$ around a closed curve $C$ is given by the integral
$$
   W(F, C) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_C \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \cdot F \, ds,
   $$
where $ds$ is the differential arc length along $C$.
Since $F(x) = F(-x)$, the integrand $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \cdot F$ is antisymmetric with respect to $x$, and hence the above integral is zero.
Below is what I have in mind as the definition of the winding number.
The winding number of a vector field defined on a curve is a measure of how many times the vector field wraps around a point or curve in the plane or space. Formally, let $C$ be a closed curve in the plane or space, and let $\mathbf{F}$ be a continuous vector field defined on $C$ except possibly at finitely many points. The winding number $W(\mathbf{F}, C)$ of $\mathbf{F}$ around $C$ by the following integral:
$$
W(\mathbf{F}, C) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_C \frac{\mathbf{F}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t)}{|\mathbf{F}(t)|^2} \, dt
$$
where $\mathbf{F}(t)$ is the vector field, $\mathbf{r}(t)$ is the position vector of the curve $C$, and $t$ ranges over the parameterization of $C$.
The winding number measures how many times the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ wraps around $C$ as one traverses the curve $C$. If $W(\mathbf{F}, C)$ is an integer $n$, it indicates that the vector field $\mathbf{F}$ wraps around $C$ $n$ times in a counterclockwise direction.

Could you please include a definition of the winding number of $F$? Also, to clarify: is $F$ a section of the tangent bundle of $C$, or a section of (the pullback to $C$ of) the tangent bundle of $S^2$?

@diracdeltafunk At every point $x\in C$ the unit vector $F(x)$ in tangent to $S^2$ and not necessarily to $C$. I have included my argument and definition of the winding number.
